# Magento - Get category name in a custom product grid in homepage

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to get the name of category in a custom category products grid in homepage

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't already have a variable containing a category object, create one:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
```

Getting the name is then a simple matter of...

```
echo $category->getName();
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't see my category name, I think because it is disabled by default, can I see it also in these case ?

Comment: As a test you can see what values it has stored with `print_r($category->debug())` in place of the echo, debugging like this is a quick'n'dirty way of learning what is available.

Comment: print_r($category->debug()) gives me an Array ( ) and 

var_dump($category); gives me :
object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category)#2086 (20) { ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(16) "catalog_category" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(8) "category" ["_cacheTag":protected]=> string(16) "catalog_category" ["_useFlatResource":protected]=> bool(false) ["_designAttributes":"Mage_Catalog_Model_Category":private]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(13) "custom_design" [1]=> string(19) "custom_design_apply" [2]=> string(18) "custom_design_from" [3]=> string(16) "custom_design_to" [4]=> string(11)

Comment: ...and...
"page_layout" [5]=> string(20) "custom_layout_update" } ["_treeModel":protected]=> NULL ["_defaultValues":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_lockedAttributes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_isDeleteable":protected]=> bool(true) ["_isReadonly":protected]=> bool(false) ["_resourceName":protected]=> string(16) "catalog/category" ["_resource":protected]=> NULL ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=> string(27) "catalog/category_collection" ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=> bool(true) ["_isObjectNew":protected]=> NULL ["_data":protected]=>

Comment: ...and...

array(0) { } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(false) ["_origData":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_idFieldName":protected]=> string(9) "entity_id" ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false) }

Comment: The `Array()` shows the category model you have is empty, probably you tried to load a non-existent category, make sure the category ID you are using is valid.

Comment: Should I directly put the number with le category ID ??
I want to use the phtml file for 2 categories